# removing elements from an array from another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i need to remove the array from another array.Below is the code that i had tried

```
var dummyObj = ["item1"];
var dummyArray = [ "item1", "item3", "item2"];


var data1=removeFromArray(dummyArray, dummyObj);

console.log("data1"+data1)

function removeFromArray(array, item)
{
while((index = array.indexOf(item)) > -1)
array.splice(index,1);
return array
}
```

below is my output

```
item1,item3,item2
```

But the required output is

```
item3,item2
```

Dont know where i am going wrong.Any help regarding this will be much helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You argument  item is an   is an array object so you have to use it like  item[0]

```
 while((index = array.indexOf(item[0])) > -1)
```

if dummyObj contains for than one values then you have to add an extra loop

```
function removeFromArray(array, item)
{
for(var j=0;j<item.length;j++){
while((index = array.indexOf(item[j])) > -1)
array.splice(index,1);

}
return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that, `item` is actually `dummyObj` which is an array and that does not exist in `dummyArray`. That is why it fails to remove it.

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
dummyArray = dummyArray.filter(function(currentItem) {
    return dummyObj.indexOf(currentItem) === -1;
});

console.log(dummyArray);    // [ 'item3', 'item2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Underscore.js, a javascript utility belt:

http://underscorejs.org/#difference

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors there:

```
while((index = array.indexOf(item)) > -1)
```

Should be

```
while((index = array.indexOf(item) > -1)
```

Also you need to loop through both dummyArray and dummyObj, because your **item** variable is actually dummyObj, so you need to loop through it to check each element separately.